# Decision Binary Tree implementation in Python with recursive function

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

I am beginner in data structure and I am using Python to create a decision binary tree from a list, the elements of the list should be in the leaf. the length of the list is always a pair number.

I create a data structure of binary tree:

```
class BinaryTree:
   def __init__(self, value):
      self.value= value
      self.left = None
      self.right = None

   def insert_left(self, value):
      if self.left == None:
         self.left  = BinaryTree(value)
      else:
         new_node = BinaryTree(value)
         new_node.left = self.left
         self.left= new_node

   def insert_right(self, value):
      if self.right== None:
         self.right= BinaryTree(value)
      else:
         new_node = BinaryTree(value)
         new_node.right= self.right
         self.right= new_node

   def get_value(self):
      return self.value

   def get_left(self):
      return self.left

   def get_right(self):
      return self.right
```

I create a recursive function to implement a tree :

```
def cons_tree(leaflist):
   size = len(leaflist)
   tag = int(math.log(size)/math.log(2))
   return cons_tree_sub(tag, leaflist)

def cons_tree_sub(tag, leaflist):
   size = len(leaflist)
   abd = BinaryTree(tag)
   if size < 3:
      abd.insert_left(leaflist[0])
      abd.insert_right(leaflist[1])
   else :
      mid= size//2
      subList1= leaflist[:mid]
      subList2= leaflist[mid:]
      #the code in java is :
      #return new Node(tag,cons_tree_sub(tag-1,subList1),cons_tree_sub(tag-1,subList2));
      abd.insert_left(cons_tree_sub(tag-1, subList1))
      abd.insert_right(cons_tree_sub(tag-1, subList2))
   return abd

def display(T):
   if T != None:
      print (T.get_value(),display(T.get_left()),display(T.get_right()))

abd = cons_tree([False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False])
display(abd)
```

When I execute the program I have this result :

```
                           _________________________3__________________________
                          /                                                    \
<__main__.BinaryTree object at 0x000002B3F25E8F70> <__main__.BinaryTree object at 0x000002B3F25E87C0>
```

I understand that when I insert in the left or the right I insert a tree not a value, how I can get to implement all the tree children in a recursive function

I tried to do get_value() for the return function because it returns a tree :

```
abd.insert_left(cons_tree_sub(tag-1, subList1).get_value())
abd.insert_right(cons_tree_sub(tag-1, subList2).get_value())
```

but I have a result of uncomplete tree :

```
 3
/ \
2 2
```

The result I want is :

```
           __________3__________
          /                     \
      ____2____             ____2_____
     /         \           /          \
   __1__      _1__       __1__      __1__
  /     \    /    \     /     \    /     \
False True True False False True False False
```

Comment: Your question does not include the `display` method. Also: is your input size always a power of 2? Or in other words, are you always creating a perfect binary tree?

Comment: @trincot I didn't put it because I don't want to put a lot of unnecessary code in my question. my question is focus on the `cons_tree_sub` function

Comment: Please also check my other questions...

Comment: A minor point, but it's best to avoid using key words such as `list` as variable names. It can lead to confusions when you end up calling the in build `list` function rather than your variable. It also makes you code harder to read

Comment: @EdgarH yes I not using this key words but I right like this on the question to be an explicit question

Comment: @trincot  just determine the height of the tree from the list,  for exemple the length of this list is 8 then `2 power(tag) = 8` , the height is tag here is 3 (the root is 3) 
yes I am creating a `perfect binary tree` 
main call pass a value for `tag` is `tag = int(math.log(size)/math.log(2))`

Comment: I would call that more than a minor point. Not only is it extremely confusing, but python bindings are dynamic, not scoped. This means that if one of your variables is named `list`, and you call a function that itself calls `list` under the hood, all hell will break loose. Please, please don't call any variable `list`.

Comment: @Stef yes I am with you on this point but I just change it to ask the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
abd.insert_left(cons_tree_sub(tag-1, subList1))
```

Because `abd.insert_left` expects a *value* as argument, but you pass it a node instance (as this is what `cons_tree_sub` returns).

So do:

```
abd.left = cons_tree_sub(tag-1, subList1)
```

...or create a setter, or alter `insert_left` so that it can also deal with node instances.

I would change the node constructor so it can optionally take arguments for left and right children:

```
def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self.value= value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```

I would also use a more atomic base case for the recursion, and make use of `math.log2`.

Then you could reduce code and write `cons_tree` as follows:

```
def cons_tree(lst):
    size = len(lst)
    if size == 1:
        return BinaryTree(lst[0])
    mid = size//2
    return BinaryTree(int(math.log2(size)), cons_tree(lst[:mid]), cons_tree(lst[mid:]))
```

Comment: See it run [on repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma702736435459839). I made my own simplistic `display`, but it works fine.

Comment: yes I had just a small bug in `display` function !! thank  you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're using a top-down approach, constructing the tree from the top and inserting values in the tree.

I suggest a bottom-up approach, constructing the tree from the bottom and merging two small trees into a bigger tree.

One way to do that is to add a new `.__init__` method to class `Tree`, in order to allow constructing a tree from two subtrees:

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, v, l=None, r=None):
        self.value = v
        self.left = l
        self.right = r
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.left is None and self.right is None:
            return repr(self.value)
        else:
            return 'T({},{},{})'.format(self.value, self.left, self.right)

def build_tree(seq):
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return Tree(1, seq[0], None)
    elif len(seq) == 2:
        return Tree(1, seq[0], seq[1])
    else:
        m = (len(seq) + 1) // 2
        l = build_tree(seq[:m])
        r = build_tree(seq[m:])
        return Tree(max(l.value, r.value) + 1, l, r)

print( build_tree([False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]) )
# T(3,T(2,T(1,False,True),T(1,True,False)),T(2,T(1,False,True),T(1,False,False)))
```