# How to sum depths of nodes in a binary tree- why is my output 0 for all tests?- I can't debug as I don't know how to write tests for trees

Tags: python, recursion

Hi I am answering a question on Binary trees, where we are asked to return the sum of the depths of the binary tree.

Here's an example:

[image]

I would like to use recursion to solve the problem, and I've written some code to do it:

```
def nodeDepths(root):
    if not root: 
        return 0 
    runningSumDepth = 0 
    rootToLeadDepthCalc(root,runningSumDepth,0)
    return newDepth
    
def rootToLeadDepthCalc(root,runningSumDepth,currDepth):
    newDepth = 0 
    
    if not root: 
        return 
    
    newDepth = currDepth + rootToLeadDepthCalc(root.left,newDepth,currDepth+1)
    newDepth = curreDepth + rootToLeadDepthCalc(root.right,newDepth,currDepth+1)


# This is the class of the input binary tree.
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

I am getting a 'int' and 'Nonetype' cannot be added error. But why doesn't my base case catch this?

Comment: modify your method `__init__` so that it allows you to build trees directly: `def __init__(self, value, left = None, right = None): self.value = value; self.left = left; self.right = right`. Now you can build trees directly: `t = BinaryTree(3, BinaryTree(2, BinaryTree(1), None), BinaryTree(7, BinaryTree(5, BinaryTree(4), BinaryTree(6)), BinaryTree(8, BinaryTree(7, ))))`

Comment: The main mistake is that int variables are not mutable types in pythons. This means that when you do `runningSumDepth += currDepth` in a recursive call, this update is not reverberated to the caller.

Comment: Try this code for instance: define a function `f` with `def f(x): x += 3` then try to use it: `x = 2; f(x); print(x)`

Comment: The easiest workaround is to add a `return something` in `rootToLeadDepthCalc` to return the result of the calculation, and use that returned value in the caller.

Comment: Thanks so much Stef, this makes a lot of sense. I was wondering why I'm having this issue, I came across something similar before trying to update int in the same way. Putting it together it makes sense now. Let me rewrite the code returning to rootToLeadDepthCalc

Comment: Steph, from your code above, how can I print the tree?

Comment: See the answers and comments to that question about a very similar class Tree to see three different ways to print the tree: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273358/decision-binary-tree-implementation-in-python-with-recursive-function